# Why google cannot detect QApages for a title?

Tags: seo, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets-tool

I'm testing Stack Overflow website using Google schema tester tool and it throws an error for the title:

[image]

Any idea why Google cannot determine that title as a QAwebpage? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're using both `name` and `title` to declare the page's title.

```
<meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="title name" content="Why google cannot detect QApages for a title?" />
```

The latter (`title`) isn't part of `QAPage` (see https://schema.org/QAPage), hence the error.

Screenshot shows full validation after editing per the above.

[image]

Comment: Still the error exists https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4oP8.png

Comment: @MartinAJ That's because you haven't removed the problem. The itemprop needs to be: `itemprop="name"`

Comment: Also as a  consult, do you think it would be either write that schema in Microdata or JSON-LD? and why?